# Printing the kth smallest in a BST, difficulty applying recursion

Tags: php, data-structures

I'm currently using the follow code to perform in inorder traversal of a BST.  My problem is getting all calculations to stop once the kth smallest is reached.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/XMGcxz

My problem is with the following function

```
public function _kthSmallest($node, $k){        

    if($node->left != NULL){
        $this->_kthSmallest($node->left, $k);
    }        
    echo $node->data . ' ';
    self::$counter++;
    echo self::$counter . "<br/>";

    /*
    if(self::$counter >= $k){
        return $node->data;
    }        
    */    

    if($node->right != NULL){

        $this->_kthSmallest($node->right, $k);
    }        
}
```

If I uncomment this code I run into problems because the root node always gets printed.

```
/*
if(self::$counter >= $k){
    return $node->data;
}        
*/
```

Any ideas of how can stop after I reach the kth smallest?  Currently the function continues through the entire BST.

Comment: This is procedural code. Why was it tagged as OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return if `self::$counter > $k`.

Actually, you shouldn't get to that state.

Since your function seems intended to return a node, what you would do is return NULL if the count is smaller.

If the count is equal, you would return the current node.  And if a recursion returned a non-NULL, you would immediately return that same value.

Comment: My bad about `self::$counter > $k`, however even after I made that change the problem is still occurring.  I've appropriately changed the link to codepad as well as the sample code I included in my original post.  Can you provide an updated link to codepad?